# random 'div' ids to dodge adblockers

Tags: javascript, html, css, adblock

I wonder if is it possible to write a website in html+css+js that uses random div id-s and classes to dodge adblockers, but is also easy to maintain (I mean that its programmer wouldn't go mad after an hour or two).

Comment: Yes, it almost certainly is.

Comment: Just inspect the gmail source code.

Comment: @jantimon .. adblock gets passed gmail , and everything else really

Answer (score 1):

Many adblockers block the JavaScript that populates the divs, so random ids would not affect them.

A different approach would be to test whether the ads loaded and then display a message that the ads have been blocked so the content is limited.

Comment: If you go to the 8tracks website , you will see that they provide this try of functionality.